# Intellisense disabled in XAML editor for Silverlight 5 and Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, xaml, intellisense, silverlight-5.0

Some days ago the XAML editor of my Silverlight 5 project in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 stopped to work. Before it worked well.
I see around in web that it's a known issue, but I can't find the cause and, specially, the solution (if it exists).

Pileggi

I've updated my question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976820/visual-studio-2010-sp1-silverlight-5-behavior-disables-xaml-intellisense

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when you add an xmlns definitions that prevent intellisense.

There are two major causes for this:

1. You reference a namespace in the same assembly that the xaml resides in and it looks something like this:

   `xmlns:myLabel="clr-namespace:MyAssembly.MyNamespace"`

   this is an easy fix, just add `;assembly=` at the end, so it looks like this:

   `xmlns:myLabel="clr-namespace:MyAssembly.MyNamespace;assembly="`
2. You reference an assembly that has internal errors that affect reflection. This is more of a problem since it's very difficult to find what is it that the reflection doesn't like. So, the only way that I know to deal with it is to remove (comment) the offending xmlns definition and work with blue squiggly-lines all over the xaml (but with intellisense) and then to add the xmlns definitions back before building the project. And yes, it's a major PITA. :(

Hope that in your case it's the first cause.

Comment: I work in VB and I write only

xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication"

It's True: if I cancel that line the intellisense works, but if I write your suggestion

xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication;assembly="

it can't recognize the types of the current assemby (local)

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the solution with the `;assembly=` in place.

Comment: I have tied but I have still the issue, Now my question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976820/visual-studio-2010-sp1-silverlight-5-behavior-disables-xaml-intellisense